# Calender using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, calendar, material-ui

Could someone help me out in creating a calendar component using react and material UI. The calendar should be similar to the one as shown in the link https://react.rocks/example/react-big-calendar . I've checked the scheduler component for material UI but as per what I have understood, it is licensed. Can someone help me out in suggesting how I can start with the design part for the calendar. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Calendars are just tables and a bunch of other tricks, its all the same basic building blocks available in the docs, keeping track of state updating ui etc. Open the material ui calendar example then inspect its html in dev tools to get an idea of whats going and where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried long time with this process and realized, we should not do that. It's painful and especially takes lots efforts, does not worth for the user requirements.

You can use another library like [this](https://onursimsek94.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#intro).

Comment: React Big Calendar
https://onursimsek94.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#intro